# Should the Backbone.Fetch method be in the Collection or the View

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js

Simple question really, where is the best place to put the Backbone.Fetch method when calling a RESTFul service URL in Backbone.js?

Should it be within the View or the collection initialisation?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to put into Backbone.Collection, create a fetch method which call the prototype of backbone's fetch method:

```
fetch : function(options) {     
   Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
},
```

then in view call fetch the method as:

```
this.collection.fetch({
    success: function(){
        $("#content").show();
        $(".loader").hide();
    }
});
```

**EDIT**: you can pass a callback in the options hash as a parameter on success.

See backbone documentation: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch

Comment: How would this work with .success method on fetch? My services are sometimes slow at responding?